# Unnecessary "file reference" warnings when building a CMake project with Xcode6

Tags: xcode, cmake

Xcode 6.0 (build version 6A267n in my case) newly warns the developer if a source file is member of multiple groups/targets.

CMake, in order to work properly, adds the main source file to several targets: my_target_name, ALL_BUILD, ZERO_CHECK. Hence, I get the following warning messages.

> 2014-08-26 13:47:48.406 xcodebuild[14099:1007] warning:  The file
>   reference for "CMakeLists.txt" is a member of multiple groups
>   ("ALL_BUILD" and "ZERO_CHECK"); this indicates a malformed project. 
>   Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but
>   membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to
>   the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to
>   the same path.
>
> 2014-08-26 13:47:48.406 xcodebuild[14099:1007] warning:  The file
>   reference for "CMakeLists.txt" is a member of multiple groups
>   ("ZERO_CHECK" and "example"); this indicates a malformed project. 
>   Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but
>   membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to
>   the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to
>   the same path.

I would like to know how to resolve this warning.

The problem is reproducible with [this minimal example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87662853/stackoverflow/minimal_example_xcode6_problem.zip) (tested with CMake 3.0.1):

```
cd minimal_example_xcode6_problem
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -G Xcode ..
xcodebuild
```

Comment: By now, I believe that this issue needs to be addressed by CMake and therefore submitted a [bug report](http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15111).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue should be solved in CMake 3.1, [scheduled](http://www.cmake.org/Bug/roadmap_page.php) for November 2014.

See [this bug report](http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15111)  for details.